# How do i improve the speed of sending requests in python?`

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im making a minecraft name sniper right now, and i wanted to ask if someone could tell me a way to send requests faster in python, currently i only use this:

```
def start_sniping(threads):
    for i in range(requests):
        try:
```

And then below there is code, that will snipe the name.
Is there a method to send requests faster? Thanks :)

Comment: is `requests` a package name? or you mean `range(requests)`

Comment: Are you already sending data async ?

Answer (score 1):

Are you already using concurrency? If not, have a look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html using the `Pool` will help you to achieve parallelism, alternatively you can use threads, which also has something similar `Pool`

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool

def send_request(x):
    ...

# 5 parallel tasks
p = Pool(5)
print(p.map(send_request, range(requests))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using django i would recommend you to check out celery,it will generally improve the speed and throughput of your applications by running the function in async along side your other functions.